# Conditional probability of drawing balls from an urn

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

Suppose that there is an urn with 3 red, 3 yellow and 3 black balls, and we are drawing without replacement.

What is the probability that the second ball is yellow, *given* that the first ball is either yellow or red?

I believe that this can be easily computed as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{8}\right)=\frac{5}{16}$$

The reasoning is that we condition on two possible events (either yellow, or red ball drawn already), so effectively going forward, there are two sample spaces (2 yellow balls remaining and 3 yellow balls remaining): since we don't know which sample space we are in, there is $\frac{1}{2}$ chance it's either.

More formally:

- Let the event that the first ball drawn is yellow be denoted as $Y_1$
- Let the event that the first ball drawn is red be $R_1$, etc...

The probability of second yellow, given that first is yellow or red can be computed using Bayes' law as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_2|(Y_1\cup R_1))=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_2\cap(Y_1\cup R_1))}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1\cup R_1)}=\\=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_2\cap Y_1)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1 \cup R_1)}+\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_2\cap R_1)}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1 \cup R_1)}=\\=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1\cup R_1)}\left(\mathbb{P}(Y_2\cap Y_1)+\mathbb{P}(Y_2\cap R_1)\right)=\\=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(Y_1\cup R_1)}\left(\mathbb{P}(Y_2|Y_1)\mathbb{P}(Y_1)+\mathbb{P}(Y_2|R_1)\mathbb{P}(R_1)\right)\\=\frac{9}{6}\left(\frac{2}{8}\frac{3}{9}+\frac{3}{8}\frac{3}{9}\right)=\\=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{8}\right)}=\frac{5}{16}$$

The boxed formula shows that the "simplified" method / assumption that I show in the first half of my answer works.

The reason I am posting this question is that I have been told that my reasoning is flawed (in fact, I gave this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/76806/probability-puzzle-from-a-quant-interview/76813#76813) to a similar question, albeit with more balls, and some commenters mentioned the logic is incorrect).

I can't see how a logic which gives the correct answer can be described as incorrect.

Comment: Is the "drawing without replacement" uniform at random?

Comment: @VezenBU: random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, as *confirmed* by listing the restricted sample space due to the conditionality imposed with associated probabilities .

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
Outcome & YY & RY & YR & RR & YB & RB \\ \hline
Probability &\frac{6}{72} & \frac{9}{72}  &\frac{9}{72}&\frac6{72} & \frac{9}{72}& \frac{9}{72}\\ \hline
\end{array}$

From the table above, it should be clear that

P($2nd$ yellow |$1st$ red or yellow) $= \frac{6+9}{48} = \frac{5}{16}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I may still ask: suppose the question would be: probability of 6th drawn ball yellow, given that in the first 5 draws, there was 1 more red ball drawn than yellow. This gives 3 possible outcomes: (0 yellow drawn already, 1 yellow drawn already, 2 yellow drawn already): I would argue we can still compute this as $$\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$ Do you agree?

Comment: [1] Btw, the conditions are impossible, $0Y+1R+3B$ <5 [2] Ok, so suppose we say we want P(yellow on draw $5$), we either have $0Y,1R,3B$ or $1Y,2R,1B$ as *given*, but they aren't equiprobable

Comment: My bad. Say there are 4 balls of each color, same question: probability of 6th drawn ball yellow, given that in the first 5 draws, there was 1 more red ball drawn than yellow. Even though the outcomes we condition on are not equiprobable, I believe we can compute the probability as: $$\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{4}{7}+\frac{3}{7}+\frac{2}{7}\right)=\frac{3}{7}$$

Comment: An interesting conundrum after a long time. I will shortly add an answer.

Comment: If you want, I can ask it as a new question?

Comment: If you think it better, you could.

Comment: Ok, let me do that.